# Using Maven dependencies in JDeveloper 12c

Tags: jsf, primefaces, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'd like to know how I can use a dependency provided by Maven in JDeveloper.

For example: I define a dependency in my pom.xml for primefaces UI components.

Why I can't use it in JDeveloper?

In the components window there are no primefaces components!

The WAR project is build properly with jars in WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Adding those kind of dependencies is not IDE depentend. It rather depends on the project type, in this case you should use a **Maven Project**. It has it's own structure organization. So the first option would be to create such a project (JDev does even have an include option for maven projects).

Nevertheless JDev 12C has it's own support mechanism, but you need to do some little configuration into your project. Here you have a good tutorial explaining it: [Introducing Maven Support in JDev 12C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ht8JgEAmrI8)

Comment: The problem is that primefaces is a library of JSF UI components. So it has a definition of its JSF components in a taglib file. In every other IDE i can see those components in the IDE. But in the JDeveloper there arent any! If i deploy the app everything works fine. But JDeveloper IDE doesnt recognize the components namespace. I have to manualy add to project configuration the absolute path to primefaces JAR in facelets taglibs in order to work... but that is a workaround.

Comment: You've asked about maven dependencies, primefaces taglib and making UI components available into the Palette are a whole different things. Please be more specific to your requirement next time.

Comment: Hello from the future. Given that JDeveloper does support being a Maven project, I advise leaving JDeveloper behind, as a whole.